# Why does resizing takes place if all the elements are ended in same bucked?

Tags: java, reflection, hashmap, hashtable

I have written below code to test the behavior of hashmap when all elements are ended in the same bucket:-

```
public class DerivedMain {

int data = 10;

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return data;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap m = new HashMap();
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        m.put(i, i);
    }

    Field tableField = null;
    try {
        tableField = HashMap.class.getDeclaredField("table");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tableField.setAccessible(true);
    Object[] table = null;
    try {
        table = (Object[]) tableField.get(m);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) 
            {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(table == null ? 0 : table.length);
}
```

}

I got the following output:-
32

Why is resizing happening even when all the elements are ending in same bucket?

Answer (score 2):

Because that's how a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) works:

> When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed.

The HashMap only knows that, once the limit has been reached, the probablility of collisions becomes too high, and it must rehash to lower that probability and leave room for future entries. It assumes a good implementation of hashCode, and has absolutely no way to know if the collisions are caused by really bad luck of by a bad implementation of hashCode.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your code and then you will find that the 'hashcode' method defined in your class 'DerivedMain'  will never be called, so all of the elements are not in the same bucket. But the real reason why the output is 32 is that the size(20) of hashmap is greater than the threshold(table.size * loadfactor).If you want to know more working details of hashmap,you should read the source code in jdk.

Comment: Why the hashcode method in my class DerivedMain will never be called if i have overridden the method?

Comment: You put `Integer`s as keys in your map. So `Integer#hashcode()` will be called. You did not override that (nor can you). You could put `DerivedMain` instances in the map instead, then your hashcode would be used (but you also need to supply an `equals`).

Comment: Ok...Thanks
Now i am changing my implementation in main class where insted of creating integer as keys now i will create as:-
   DerivedMain d = new DerivedMain();
   m.put(d, i);
Now i am getting hashmap capacity as 64. Why?